# Frame Rate Independence for Non-Linear Increases

Tags: java, frame-rate

So while working on my game, I decided that I would have a speed variable increase in the fashion

```
speed += 1/speed;
```

with the goal being that in the beginning it increases fast and then it increases slow as it gets higher. However this is being called each frame and I need to make it framerate independent, however just scaling it based on time doesn't give the same results throughout. How would I go about creating a framerate independent increase that dampens like this?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Is this a vehicle, sprite, etc.? What are the expected numerical limits of speed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will be a frame rate independent alternative for this type of movement:

```
speed = Math.log(time + 1) / Math.log(Math.E) + startingSpeed;
```

This sets speed equal to `ln(time + 1)` which increases at a rate of `1/time`. You want the `+1` because `ln(t)` is negative while t is less than 1 (and greater than zero).

Just have `time` start at zero and increase it by `deltaTime` or the equivalent every update.

Also, for the sake of performance you could store the value of `Math.log(Math.E)` in a variable and use it instead when calculating speed.

Comment: Good idea. But isn't math.log (math.e) just 1?

Comment: @Will No, it's approx. 0.4343. Math.log is log base 10. If math.log were log base e then it would be 1.